# Is it possible to manually poll and sync public CloudKit with local Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

In his [WWDC20-10650](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10650/) talk, Nick explains that Public CloudKit Databases are "polled" on application launch and after about every 30 minutes.

Is it possible to manually poll and sync with the Public CloudKit Database via a button or, for example, SwiftUI's `.refreshable` modifier?